# person voice identification/recognition

Tags: c#, voice-recognition

i want to record someones voice and then from information i get about his/her voice i recognize if that person speak again! problem is i have no information about what stats(like frequency ) cause difference to human voice, if any one could help me with how i could recognize someones voice?

while i was researching i found various libraries about speech recognition but they could not help me because my problem is very simpler! i just want to recognize The person who speaking not what he is saying.

Comment: What tells you that is simpler?

Comment: hmm..! just my initial thought! maybe it is harder!

Comment: I would qualify this problem with many different words... but "simple" is not one of it.

Comment: Given that there is speech recognition in the c# framework, but none for recognizing persons, I would say that it will be a lot harder for you.

Comment: Find a framework for this. If you can't find any, try writing one. It's not going to be easy or "simple"

Comment: Check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/166198/Recognizing-a-person-s-voice-using-C

Comment: You could do a Ph.D. in this topic. Most of the modern voice analysis/detection algorithms use 2D/3D physical vocal cord simulations to classify the different vocal degrees of freedom used to classify individuals! As was stated above - this is _not_ easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some help here, maybe: http://www.generation5.org/content/2004/noReco.asp
Based on an open source FFT library ( http://www.exocortex.org/dsp/ ), with some suggestions about how to do speaker verification.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe is not simple since the voice of the same person can sound different (for example if the person has a cold etc.) and/or if the person is speaking louder/faster/slower etc.

Another point is the separation from other sounds (background, other voices etc.).

The quality of the equipment which records the sound is very important - some systems use multiple microphones to achieve good results...

Altogether this is no easy task - esp. if you want to achieve a good detection ratio.

Basically the way to implement this is:

- implement robust sound separation
- implement a robust sound/voice pattern extraction
- create a DB with fingerprint(s) of the voice(s) you want to recognize based on ideal sound setting
- define an algorithm for comparison between your stored fingerprint(s) and the extracted/normalized sound/voice pattern (have some thresholds for "probably equal" etc. might be necessary...)
- refine your algorithms till you achieve an acceptable detection rate (take the false positive rate into account too!)

For a nice overview see http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Speaker_recognition

Answer (score 3):

See VoiceID for Linux.  It uses Sphinx and other libs and installs pretty easily.